# stargazer and omit regular expressions

Tags: r, stargazer

I am trying to use regular expressions to omit some variables in stargazer.  I finally found a working regex, but it's using the Perl standard.  This doesn't work for the base regex in R, though regexpr in R can take a perl=T option.  Given that you wrap the regex for variable sets to omit in "", you can't really pass it this option.  Any ideas on how to use perl regex with stargazer?

An example of the regex I would like to use is

```
placed.ind2*(?:(?!:switchind).)*$
```

applied to these 4 strings:

```
placed.ind2PROF SERVICES
placed.ind2TRANSPORT
placed.ind2PROF SERVICES:switchind2TRUE
placed.ind2TRANSPORT:switchind2TRUE
```

I would like the first two to be selected, but the last to be.

Comment: Can you give an example of what you tried?

Answer (score 2):

Starting from version 4.0 (on CRAN now), you can run stargazer with the argument perl=TRUE to allow for Perl-compatible regular expressions in your other arguments.

Comment: awesome!  I had gotten by with just hacking up the original package, but it's good to know that it works with the versions from here on out.  Thanks, Marek!  E